# which methods require the least amount of resources?

Tags: database, cassandra, cql

I am currently working on the development of a social network with Cassandra. My problem is that I hesitate between two solutions to optimize the consumption of my server.In the first case, when a user publishes a post, it contains all the information like the nickname or the profile picture. But when the user change his nickname for example, I have to change the value for all the posts.
In case two, the information of the user and the posts are stored separately, but each time a user recovers a post he makes two commades instead of one.
In the long run, which of these solutions is the best to optimize the speed of my server?
Thank you for your answers,

Jesver

Comment: Why would you have to store the nickname and profile for all posts? Normally you would just store that information once, and any post would just have a reference to the profile.

Comment: Would you please explain what "recovers a post" means? Also, what does "commades" mean in "he makes two commades instead of one". Cheers!

Comment: @ErickRamirez when a user logs on to the platform he/she will get the last posts. The problem is that with cassandra the joins between two tables do not work. Cassandra will first have to fetch the post and then in a second time the information linked to the user. If the user information is stored in the same table as the post then the db will only have one action to do. The problem is that in this case, if a user changes his nickname for example, it will be necessary to make an update on all the posts. I wonder if this is the most optimized solution in the long run or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned that it's a social media application, so the assumption is that there can be plenty of posts by a single user. Also since you have mentioned about using Cassandra, the first scenario will not scale well for a few reasons.

1. Extensive updates can somehow be costly since it involves a read operation prior to write. It can be considered as an [Antipattern](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/2.2/cassandra/planning/planPlanningAntiPatterns.html#Readingbeforewriting).
2. The information about user will be redundant in each post. In the longer run, it will be a pain ensuring consistent user information in all the post.

The second alternative might be better in which 2 tables are created for users & posts, along with maintaining the relationship at the application level.